# Extracting data by tabs in a TSV with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a TSV file with the data separated like this

```
class  (this is tab header)
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te

criteria (this is tab header)
A   B   C   D   D   1
A   B   C   D   E   2
S   D   F   G   H   2
S   D   F   G   B   4

class  (this is tab header)
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee



criteria (this is tab header)
S   D   F   G   H   2
S   D   F   G   B   4
A   B   C   D   D   1
A   B   C   D   E   2
```

I need help writing a python script that will extract and merge all of the data for each tab into One file for respective tabs . One for class , another for tab  criteria.  The out dataset will look something like this.

```
output file for class
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee


output file for criteria
A   B   C   D   D   1
A   B   C   D   E   2
S   D   F   G   H   2
S   D   F   G   B   4
S   D   F   G   H   2
S   D   F   G   B   4
A   B   C   D   D   1
A   B   C   D   E   2
```

Thanks for your anticipated help.

Comment: what is the problem? What did you try? Where is your code? You could read all data to Python and split by empty lines (`'\n\n'`) and later make other changes in data in memory and later write all to files.

Answer (score 0):

Given the file you gave this will sort your TSV into the two lists.

It will fail if there is any not empty line above one of the `* (this is tab header)` lines.

**NB1.** as I wrote it right now it will replace the original file with the new sorted file.

**NB2.** this reads the file in memory, if you're working with huge files it might be best to read/write to a pair of  [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#tempfile.TemporaryFile) and then concatenate those.

```py
lines = {"class": [], "criteria": []}

with open("file.tsv", "r") as f:
    while line := f.readline():
        if line == "\n":
            continue
        elif line == "class  (this is tab header)\n":
            current = "class"
        elif line == "criteria (this is tab header)\n":
            current = "criteria"
        else:
            lines[current].append(line)

with open("file.tsv", "w") as f:  # note this truncates the file to 0
    f.write("class  (this is tab header)\n")
    f.writelines(lines["class"])
    f.write("criteria (this is tab header)\n")
    f.writelines(lines["criteria"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to hold suitable file handles and write the lines as they are read in. This would then work on any file size:

```py
output = {
    'class' : open('class.tsv', 'w'),
    'criteria' : open('criteria.tsv', 'w')
}

# Write suitable headers
for header, handle in output.items():
    handle.write(f"{header} (this is a tab header)\n")  

with open('input.tsv') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        if line.strip():   # skip any blank lines
            if line.startswith('class'):
                mode = 'class'
            elif line.startswith('criteria'):
                mode = 'criteria'
            else:
                output[mode].write(line)
                
for handle in output.values():
    handle.close()
```